# potentially unwanted program problem in angular live deployment

Tags: angular, angular7

When i deployed my angular project to digital ocean server, clicking on anywhere on the screen in the first page would automatically opens a new tab with potentially unwanted program, and once this happens then no other attempts will occur until the session is restarted. I have scanned my computer at which the project is developed and found no potentially unwanted programs. How can find cause of this problem. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Well searching over the internet it seems the problem is my ISP BSNL injects ads to http (non secure) sites.
To further check I connected to another service provider and found the problem is caused by BSNL as connecting to other service provider doesn't cause this problem.